# Configuring Jaeger in Spring application

Tags: spring, opentracing, jaeger

I would like to configure Jaeger in my Spring application. Somehow I cannot find a proper way to do this. Almost all Spring-Jaeger-related documentation is for Spring Boot where most of the properties are auto configured. Here's my approach. 
Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Spring config for Jaeger:

```
@Configuration
public class JagerConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public io.opentracing.Tracer jaegerTracer() {
        Map<String, String> tags = new HashMap<>();
        tags.put(Constants.TRACER_HOSTNAME_TAG_KEY, "localhost");

        CompositeReporter reporter = new CompositeReporter(new LoggingReporter(), remoteReporter());


        return new Builder("myTestSpringApp")
                .withSampler(new ConstSampler(true))
                .withMetricsFactory(new InMemoryMetricsFactory())
                .withReporter(remoteReporter())
                .withTags(tags)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RemoteReporter remoteReporter() {
        return new RemoteReporter.Builder().withSender(new UdpSender("localhost", 6831, 0)).build();
    }
}
```

Jaeger is running locally in docker on port 6831.

```
docker run -d -p6831:6831/udp -p16686:16686 jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
```

Once my application starts, I noticed that application slows down considerably, I assume that is because of metrics logged heavily to console by LoggingReporter.

However, My Spring app does not show up in Jaeger UI. In the beginning I would like to trace my REST endpoints. Can someone point me in the right direction why my app is missing from UI and how I configure Jaeger properly? Is there perhaps a sample project with Spring+Jaeger that does not rely on outdated Jaeger?

Comment: Are you seeing spans being logged via your logging facility? You might want to check this blog post, to help troubleshoot: https://medium.com/jaegertracing/help-something-is-wrong-with-my-jaeger-installation-68874395a7a6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone else would like to set up Jaeger in spring project, here's what I did:

Add dependencies to pom:

```
<properties>
    <opentracing.spring.web.version>0.3.4</opentracing.spring.web.version>
    <opentracing.jdbc.version>0.0.12</opentracing.jdbc.version>
    <opentracing.spring.configuration.starter.version>0.1.0</opentracing.spring.configuration.starter.version>
    <opentracing.spring.jaeger.starter.version>0.2.2</opentracing.spring.jaeger.starter.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentracing-spring-web-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${opentracing.spring.web.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentracing-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${opentracing.jdbc.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentracing-spring-tracer-configuration-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${opentracing.spring.configuration.starter.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentracing-spring-jaeger-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${opentracing.spring.jaeger.starter.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Set up you web.xml to register new tracing filter *tracingFilter* to intercept REST API:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>tracingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>tracingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Register jaeger tracer in spring mvc:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <bean class="io.opentracing.contrib.spring.web.interceptor.TracingHandlerInterceptor">
            <constructor-arg ref="jaegerTracer" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Set up the *tracingFilter* bean we described in web.xml:

```
import io.opentracing.Tracer;
import io.opentracing.contrib.web.servlet.filter.TracingFilter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
public class JaegerFilterConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public TracingFilter tracingFilter(Tracer tracer) {
        return new TracingFilter(tracer);
    }
}
```

Finally define jaeger tracer spring configuration:

```
import io.jaegertracing.internal.JaegerTracer;
import io.jaegertracing.internal.metrics.NoopMetricsFactory;
import io.jaegertracing.internal.reporters.RemoteReporter;
import io.jaegertracing.internal.reporters.RemoteReporter.Builder;
import io.jaegertracing.internal.samplers.ProbabilisticSampler;
import io.jaegertracing.thrift.internal.senders.UdpSender;
import io.opentracing.Tracer;
import io.opentracing.util.GlobalTracer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;


@Configuration
public class JaegerConfiguration implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {


    private static final int JAEGER_PORT = 6831;
    private static final String JAEGER_HOST = "localhost";
    private static final String JAEGER_SERVICE_NAME = "my-awesome-jaeger";
    private static final double SAMPLING_RATE = 0.5;
    @Autowired
    private Tracer tracer;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public Tracer jaegerTracer(RemoteReporter remoteReporter) {
        return new JaegerTracer.Builder(JAEGER_SERVICE_NAME)
                .withReporter(remoteReporter)
                .withMetricsFactory(new NoopMetricsFactory()).withSampler(new ProbabilisticSampler(SAMPLING_RATE))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RemoteReporter remoteReporter() {
        return new Builder().withSender(new UdpSender(JAEGER_HOST, JAEGER_PORT, 0)).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        if (!GlobalTracer.isRegistered()) {
            GlobalTracer.register(tracer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any sample application which shows this implementation in detail?

Comment: you san use sample project from Opentracing:
https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-jaeger

Answer (score 0):

I have got following gradle dependencies working,

```
    implementation "io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-spring-cloud-starter:0.1.13"
    implementation "io.jaegertracing:jaeger-client:0.31.0"
```

Following tracer bean configuration,

```
  @Bean
    public io.opentracing.Tracer initTracer() {
        Configuration.SamplerConfiguration samplerConfig = new Configuration.SamplerConfiguration().withType("const").withParam(1);
        return Configuration.fromEnv("sprint-service").withSampler(samplerConfig).getTracer();
    }
```

And then the spans can be recorded as

```
Span sprintSpan = tracer.buildSpan("my-span-name").withTag("player", player).start();

// some business functionality

sprintSpan.finish();
```

Here is the working example you can refer https://github.com/krushnatkhawale/jaeger-with-spring-boot-web-app

Comment: question was explicitly about spring application, not spring boot. Thanks for the input though

Comment: Don't think it will make much of a difference in spring applications. The example provided is of a spring boot application but the configuration above should work for vanila spring applications as well.